# clickhouse config kafka sasl for specific topic&consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

ClickHouse version: version 22.6.1.1468 (official build)

I want to create a kafka engine table.

1. Kafka is verified by sasl.
2. The topic to be consumed is `test_topic`.
3. The consumer group is `test_consumer_group`, and the password for this consumer to access `test_topic` is 123456.

I add a config file named kafka.xml under config.d and restart clickhous. I've tried two kinds of config, but none is right.

**first config**

```
<yandex>
    <kafka>
        <kafka_topic>
            <name>test_topic</name>
            <sasl_username>test_consumer_group</sasl_username>
            <sasl_password>123456</sasl_password>
            <security_protocol>SASL_PLAINTEXT</security_protocol>
            <sasl_mechanisms>SCRAM-SHA-256</sasl_mechanisms>
        </kafka_topic>
    </kafka>
</yandex>
```

err log: Failed to set kafka.topic: No such configuration property: "kafka.topic"

**second config**

```
<yandex>
    <kafka>
        <kafka_test_topic>
            <sasl_username>test_consumer_group</sasl_username>
            <sasl_password>123456</sasl_password>
            <security_protocol>SASL_PLAINTEXT</security_protocol>
            <sasl_mechanisms>SCRAM-SHA-256</sasl_mechanisms>
        </kafka_test_topic>
    </kafka>
</yandex>
```

err log: Failed to set kafka.gnome.druid.url.dws: No such configuration property: "kafka.gnome.druid.url.dws"

Can anyone give a complete&right example?
Or do I have to use `named_collections` at the end of this article(https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-integrations/altinity-kb-kafka/altinity-kb-adjusting-librdkafka-settings/).  Indeed I don't have different kafka clusters. I only need sasl config for specific topic&consumer.

Thanks!

Comment: The topic list and group name go under `named_collections`. The `<kafka>` element cannot be renamed